# How to return multiple images from an API with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, api

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to let users choose 1-50 images and it catches an error if I request more than 15 images but in the console it says "success". Once it catches the error above 15 images then I cannot submit to display even less than 15 images. Would I need to change something in the displayResults function or down below in the watchForm function where I have ```const numInput = $("#num-dog").val();?

````
function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  $(".results-img").empty();
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.message.length; i++) {
    $(".results-img").append(
      `<li><img src="${responseJson.message[i]}" class="results-img"></li>`
    );
    //display the results section
  }
  console.log(displayResults);
  $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
}

function getDogImages(numInput) {
  let newUrl = randomUrl + numInput;

  fetch(newUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch((error) => alert("Something went wrong. Try again later."));
}

function watchForm() {
  $("form").submit((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const numInput = $("#num-dog").val();
    getDogImages(numInput);
  });
}

$(function () {
  console.log("App loaded! Waiting for submit!");
  watchForm();
});
}```


Here is part of the HTML:

```<section id="container">
        <h1>Dog API APP</h1>
        <form id="dogform">
            <label for="number of random dog images to display">How many dogs would you like to see?</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" max="50" id="num-dog" value="" required>
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit!" >
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="results" class="hidden">
        <h2>Here are your dogs!</h2>
        <ul class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
    </section>```
````

Comment: are you using chrome as your browser?

Comment: Yes I am. But the course I am in told me that the input ```<input type="number" min="1" max="50" id="num-dog" value="" required>``` is in HTML but not properly displayed in JS so I am confused since only a few images will display up to 15.

Comment: show your return API...

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure that the problem is at API and not your code.

Comment: Yeah, it ended up being the API and not an issue with the code. Thanks!